# Find 2D array max and min

Tags: java

This is the original prompt:

> Find the maximum value and minimum value in milesTracker. Assign the maximum value to maxMiles, and the minimum value to minMiles. Sample output for the given program:
>
> ```
> Min miles: -10 
> Max miles: 40
> ```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraysKeyValue {
  public static void main (String [] args) {   
    final int NUM_ROWS = 2;
    final int NUM_COLS = 2;
    int [][] milesTracker = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int maxMiles = 0; 
    int minMiles = 0; 

    milesTracker[0][0] = -10;
    milesTracker[0][1] = 20;
    milesTracker[1][0] = 30;
    milesTracker[1][1] = 40;

    for(i=0;i<NUM_ROWS;++i) {
     
       for(j=0;j<NUM_COLS;++j) {
         
          if (milesTracker[i][j]<minMiles){
              minMiles = milesTracker[i][j]; 
          }
          else if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){
              maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
          }
       } 
    }

    System.out.println("Min miles: " + minMiles);
    System.out.println("Max miles: " + maxMiles);
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
  Testing with milesTracker = {{-10, 20}, {30, 40}}
```

Your output:

```
Min miles: -10
Max miles: 40

   Testing with milesTracker = {{73, 0}}
```

Your output:

```
Min miles: 0
Max miles: 73

✖   Testing with milesTracker = {{-5}, {-93}, {-259}}
```

Expected output:

```
Min miles: -259
Max miles: -5
```

Your output:

```
Min miles: -259
Max miles: 0
```

Why is the last test failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to @Fikolev's answer: If you are only allowed to edit the loop bodies, you can move the initialization there:

```
for(i=0;i<NUM_ROWS;++i) {
  for(j=0;j<NUM_COLS;++j) {
    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
      maxMiles = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
      minMiles = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    }
  ...
```

Comment: Where in the loop bodies would I put this code snippet?

Comment: Now it does not pass the second test

Comment: Did you incorporate all other changes? And what _is_ the second test? Honestly do you expect us to do your homework assignments?

Comment: Yes I made the exact changes that you did above; however, I am overall just confused on how it works and why it is not passing the tests.

Comment: I figured it out, I think I just had a small error somewhere. Thank you for your help. Sorry to cause you any inconvenience or frustration

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize your initial values differently.

```
int maxMiles = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
int minMiles = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Initializing them both to 0 leads to problems as you can see in the example with only negative values in the matrix. If you have only positive numbers, `minMiles` will stay 0 and will be wrong as you'll never get a value smaller than the initial 0.

For `minValue` you need to make sure that whatever you have in the array is smaller than the initial value, hence you assign it the maximal possible value of the type you use. For `maxValue` it's the opposite.

Another possible error is the `else if` condition.

```
if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles) {
    minMiles = milesTracker[i][j]; 
} else if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles) {
    maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
}
```

These two are not mutually exclusive. What if you reach a number that is both larger than your current `maxMiles` and smaller than the current `minMiles`? It can certainly happen and you'll fail to update one of them, in your case - `maxMiles`.

Comment: The only place that I can edit is where the for and nested for loops are

Comment: The program cannot function correctly if you're not allowed to edit the initial values. I edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
            minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }

        if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles) {
            maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }

        else if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles) {
            minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraysKeyValue {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int NUM_ROWS = 2;
      final int NUM_COLS = 2;
      int [][] milesTracker = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int maxMiles = 0; // Assign with first element in milesTracker before loop
      int minMiles = 0; // Assign with first element in milesTracker before loop

      milesTracker[0][0] = -10;
      milesTracker[0][1] = 20;
      milesTracker[1][0] = 30;
      milesTracker[1][1] = 40;

      /* Your solution goes here  */
      for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {

         for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {

            if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
               maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
               minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
            }

               if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles) {
                  maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
               }

               else if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles) {
                 minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
               }

            }

         }

      System.out.println("Min miles: " + minMiles);
      System.out.println("Max miles: " + maxMiles);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign with first element in milesTracker before loop

```
maxMiles = milesTracker[0][0];
minMiles = milesTracker[0][0];

for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {     
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
        if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles) {
            maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];            
        }
        if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles) {
           minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];  
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Filkolev is  really good, but you can be even shorter:

```
//The solution requires students to initialize max_miles (or maxMiles) or and min_miles (or minMiles) before writing their nested for loop. 
maxMiles = milesTracker[0][0];
minMiles = milesTracker[0][0];

//loops
for (i = 0; i <NUM_ROWS; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; ++j) {
        if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles) {
            maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
        else {
            minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the confused people who just want to copy paste the final answer -

```
/* Your solution goes here  */
maxMiles = milesTracker[0][0];
minMiles = milesTracker[0][0];


for(i = 0; i <= NUM_ROWS - 1; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j <= NUM_COLS - 1; ++j){
        if(milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles){
            minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
        if(milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){
            maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your maxMiles as a very small negative (unrealistic input) number and a large minMiles, basically any number will satisfy the condition to become the next max/min and as iterations go, you will eventually find a true max and min.

So, I am doing this exact same problem right now as homework and I came up with this:

```
  maxMiles = -9999;
  minMiles = 9999;
  for (i = 0; i < milesTracker.length; i++){
     for (j = 0; j < milesTracker[i].length; j++){
        if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles){
           minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
        if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles) {
           maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];  
        }
        
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Insert array coordinates before you start your for loops:

EX:

```
minMiles=milesTracker[0][0];
maxMiles=milesTracker[0][0];

for(i...){max
    for(j...){min
```

Comment: There is already an answer that suggests to initialize these two variables. Using very reasonable defaults. Your answer is not adding anything of value.